# open email client through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-binding, mailto

is there anyway through which I can open more than one email client, (on a single click) in java script, I know how to use mailto but don't know how to open multiple clients
this code opens the client on each reload.

```
window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
```

Any help in this regard Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you want it to load the mail client on a click rather than every time the page refreshes, you want it attached to a click event, something like this :

```
<button class="button">Open Email</button>
```

Using jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
       window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here"; 
    });
});
```

**Update**

If you want it to load multiple instances of the client, just duplicate the `window.location.href` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
       window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
       window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject2&body=message%20goes%20here";
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to launch it more than once

Comment: Yes working ok in Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google chrome

Comment: Try this one for chrome, i've added a slight delay on the second open.. http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ws7/2/

Comment: Looks like chrome doesn't like window.location.href being fired twice by one event. Will only fire the second one. And won't fire on a setTimeout. I'll try a few more things see if we can work around this.

Comment: so there is no patch for Google Chrome?

Comment: I haven't managed to find a fix as of yet I'm afraid! I will try and look a bit further into it tomorrow!!

Comment: All the above Fiddle links are broken, Error 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to launch external applications from JavaScript in a Browser.
mailto only launches the MUA which is configured as the default in the system-settings.

Comment: i meant the same, launching more than 1 default client on single click

Comment: At the risk of sounding.. thick, what is MUA ?

Comment: MUA stands for Mail User Agent